# What does '???' in values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

`global: environment: ??? environmentSubdomain: ???`

This is values.yaml i came across and wondering what does the '???' mean here ?

I did try to look the yaml ref docs didn't see anything on this

Comment: Or the original character is a non-Latin character, because the encoding cannot be parsed, resulting in `?`. You need to check the corresponding encoding or language settings.

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing, probably just that the one that created the file did not know what value to put there and used it as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. That value is actually text your viewer/editor cannot decode (Which should be rare, considering unicode is the norm these days)
2. The more likely cause; and this is assuming the formatting of your question is wrong and it should be formatted like something this:

```yaml
global:
  environment: ???
  environmentSubdomain: ???
```

If this is the case, then it is most likely the chart author (Assuming this yaml is from a Helm chart) is using (or intending users to use) override yamls, which override a subset of values of the base values yaml like this:

`helm upgrade --install --atomic --name my-chart my-charts/chart-name --values overrides.yaml`

So basically, the "default" values for `global.environment`, for example, would be "???" but you are expected to override that with your own `values.yaml` or via `--set switches`